wsl + vscodeでC++のデバッグができない
目的
Using C++ and WSL in VS Codeを参考に、WSL + VSCodeでC/C++のdebugを試みています。
Run helloworld.cppのところで、Run C/C++ Fileをクリックしたところ、

とのエラーが出ました。
試行錯誤
ということで、
{
// IntelliSense を使用して利用可能な属性を学べます。
// 既存の属性の説明をホバーして表示します。
// 詳細情報は次を確認してください: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) 起動",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/ABC/a.out",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "gdb の再フォーマットを有効にする",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            },
            {
                "description": "逆アセンブリ フレーバーを Intel に設定",
                "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }

]
}

とlaunch.jsonに書きました。しかし

と出ました。
わからんこと
g++をターミナルから動かすときは実行ファイルについて自分で場所と名前を指定できるけど、vscodeの機能から動かすときはどこにどんな名前で吐き出されるのか
備考

私は普段Code Runnerを使っています。設定は次の通り。

"cpp": "cd $workspaceRoot && g++ $dir$fileName -o bin/$fileNameWithoutExt.exe && bin/$fileNameWithoutExt.exe",

もっとも今回に限っては使っていません。

programの末尾にある)に違和感がありますが、この記述は意図したものですか？

ミスです。失礼しました。

まずは参照している「手順そのまま」で実行してうまくいくことを目指してはどうでしょうか？手順だと WSL の中の VSCode を起動しており、$HOME/projects/helloworld にプログラムを配置しています。あなたが試している src/ABC/ なんてパスは出てきません。 / 備考の情報も Windows でコンパイルする際の話だと思うので、今回は不要だと思います。

同様の結果になりました。リンク先にChoose g++ build and debug active file from the list of detected compilers on your system.の一文が出てくるのがおわかりかと思いますが、ここでselect a configurationが出てこないのです。tasks.jsonも生成されないし、素人目にはまずコンパイルすらされていないように見えます。

Run VS Code in WSL の手順を確認したうえで、他のユーザーが同じ問題を再現できるようにあなた自身が実際に行った手順を質問に追記してください。

tasks.jsonにビルドのためのタスクを書かないとたぶんビルドされないですね。
プロジェクト直下の.vscodeフォルダに手動でtasks.jsonを作って、記入すればいけると思います。
tasks.jsonについて


Windowsでの開発経験はありますか？
Linuxでの開発経験はありますか？
クロスコンパイルやリモートデバッグの経験はありますか？

質問の内容はこれらすべてを混ぜ合わせた「Windows上でLinuxプログラムのリモートデバッグを行う方法」のようです。それぞれ個々の知識がなければ、つまずいたときにどの部分に問題があったのか切り分けできないでしょう。
まずはそれぞれについて知識を得てから挑戦することをお勧めします。

まずは、いったんVSCodeやできればWSLのOSやコンパイラなど、一切合財アンインストールしてから、ネットで溢れかえっている解説記事を参考に最初からインストールしていきましょう。
その上でわからないこと、できないことがあれば、その参考にしたページを提示したうえで聞きましょう。
どういう環境でセットアップしてるかわからん他人の環境、おまけにそこでなにをやらかしてるのかさえ不明なものを相手に、アドバイスってのはできませんよ

何かしら環境を構築するのならいざ知らず一ツールの機能を利用するためにOSの立ち上げからやり直すのはきついです。
今回に限らずなにか詰まったときにまいどまいど一からやり直していては日が暮れます。
必要な情報があれば提示しますので…

なら、あなたが不要と思うものは省略し、できるだけやり直す形でやり直しましょう。なにが悪いのかさえわからない、ってのではどーにもなりません。せめて、ここからここまでは初期状態で、設定はこうなってと、他人があなたの文章で全く同じ環境が構築できるぐらいに詳しく説明しましょう。そこまでやってやっと入口ですが。
